# Can grid column include a dropdown list?

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu, grid, devexpress

Hi 
I have such requirement, but I don't know whether it could be implemented or not:
A grid view with 4 columns: column 1, column2, column3 and column4. Among the 4 columns, for column 3, each cell contains a dropdown list control. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: absolutely. which control are you using and is this winforms, wpf, silverlight or asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if you are using web application, you can use the DataGrid1_ItemDataBound event:

> if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem ||
>         e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
>         {
>         string[] options = { "Option1", "Option2", "Option3" };

```
  DropDownList list = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ItemDropDown");
  list.DataSource = options;
  list.DataBind();
```

> }
>      else if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
>      {
>         string[] options = { "OptionA", "OptionB", "OptionC" };

```
  DropDownList list = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("HeaderDropDown");
  list.DataSource = options;
  list.DataBind();
```

1. if you are using windows app you have to design the column with type of dataggridcell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You might need to bind the data using the OnItemDatabound event, but it depends on what/where your data sources are (ie are they code behind or drag and drop).

Certainly possible.